# ZF2 Validating the form bound with an Entity

Tags: php, validation, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, fieldset

I'm binding the form with a Doctrine Entity using:

```
$form->bind($user);
```

The form is using Fieldsets.
Then I try to attach validation to the form:

```
$form->setInputFilter($userFormValidation->getInputFilter());
```

Where the validations looks like:

```
namespace User\Form;

use Zend\InputFilter\Factory as InputFactory;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterAwareInterface;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterInterface;

class UserFormValidation implements InputFilterAwareInterface
{

    protected $inputFilter;                       // <-- Add this variable


    // Add content to these methods:
    public function setInputFilter(InputFilterInterface $inputFilter)
    {
        throw new \Exception("Not used");
    }

    public function getInputFilter()
    {
        if (!$this->inputFilter) {
            $inputFilter = new InputFilter();
            $factory     = new InputFactory();

            $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                'name'     => 'input-username',
                'required' => true,
                'filters'  => array(
                    array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                    array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                ),
                'validators' => array(
                    array(
                        'name'    => 'StringLength',
                        'options' => array(
                            'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                            'min'      => 10,
                            'max'      => 50,
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            )));

            $this->inputFilter = $inputFilter;
        }

        return $this->inputFilter;
    }
}
```

The form never gets validated and when I'm trying to display all validation errors by using $form->getMessages() I'm getting an empty array.

Has anyone come across this issue?

Comment: please show the code where the actual bind and validation is being done.

Comment: Are you doing `$form->isValid()` anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I've now fixed the issue. The problem was caused by the use of the

```
$form->setInputFilter()
```

function with the form that has nested fieldsets. In the class that extends Fieldset there this function:

```
class UserFieldset extends Fieldset
{
    ...
    public function getInputFilterSpecification()
    {
        return [
            'field-name' => [
            ...
            ],
        ]
    }
}
```

That implementation fixed my problems.